# user logged globally in Firebase/Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having a problem with Firebase.
I am trying to use the Node.js (Client), meaning that I am initializing the SDK on Express, and not on the client:

```
 // initializing Firebase Node.js (Client)
const configFb = {
  apiKey: "key",
  authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xxxx.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "xxxx.appspot.com"
};
firebase.initializeApp(configFb);
```

And I am also using the SDK Admin.
The problem is: Once someone logs in, this user will be the only one logged. If I open the app here, I will be logged with his account. If I sign out, this user will be signed out as well.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js client SDK was not designed for this. It currently persists the session in memory. Once the user is signed in, you will have to issue your own token and return it to the client or set it in some cookie. You will then sign out that user. Future requests will check the cookie or the token you created. This is a simplistic answer as the sessions could be invalidated and you would lose that capability here. Ideally i would recommend using the client SDK on the browser or the app instead of doing it from a server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah, I kind of figured that out, but I decided to take a chance to see if it could be another way. Because, if I authenticate on client, I would have to do all database management on client as well right? And I don't know, that sounds a lot weird to me...Any tips on this?

But what I find very weird, is that you can find in "Reference" section on firebase docs, the use of client SDK for this. What's the point then?

Comment: The Auth node.js client SDK, I think, is more useful for desktop apps built with node.js. In that case only one user is signed in at a time.

Comment: Regarding your other question, typically database runs on the client too (serverlessly). It is optimized for that. So you gain a lot by keeping things on the client side.

Comment: That makes sense @bojeil.
Thank you for your answers! :)